# Google Drive SDK - Populate .NET TreeView with Google Drive directory structure

Tags: treeview, directory, structure, google-drive-api

I'm building a VB.NET Google Drive file explorer application for reasons that you probably do not care about. I'm using the google drive v2 sdk, and I'm trying to populate a tree view control with a user's entire Google Drive directory structure (not files, just folders.) My code is working fine, however, as I feared, it is taking several minutes for users that have a whole lot of nested folders. I am using a background worker thread to populate the treeview using a delegate function. Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of doing this?

NewPopulate() is called from my code to create the background worker threads. Start here:

```
Private Sub NewPopulate()
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(ActiveUser.Email, ActiveUser.Email)
    bwPopulateTree = New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler bwPopulateTree.DoWork, AddressOf PopulateTreeStart
    AddHandler bwPopulateTree.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf PopulateTreeFinished
    bwPopulateTree.RunWorkerAsync()
    cmbActiveUsers.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateTreeStart()
    Dim children As ChildList = FileManager.GetFoldersInFolder(ActiveUser.DriveService, "root")
    PopulateTreeLoop(ActiveUser.Email, children)
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateTreeFinished()
    lblToolStripStatus.Text = "Directory listing completed."
    SaveTree()
    cmbActiveUsers.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateTreeLoop(nodeKey As String, ByVal childList As ChildList)
    If Not childList Is Nothing Then
        Dim user As GoogleUser = ActiveUser
        For Each child As ChildReference In childList.Items
            Dim successful As Boolean = False
            If TreeView1.InvokeRequired Then
                successful = TreeView1.Invoke(New m_FindAddNode(AddressOf FindAddNode), {nodeKey, child})
            Else
                successful = FindAddNode(nodeKey, child)
            End If
            Dim children As ChildList = FileManager.GetFoldersInFolder(user.DriveService, child.Id)
            If Not children Is Nothing Then
                PopulateTreeLoop(child.Id, children)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    End Sub

Private Function FindAddNode(nodeKey As String, child As ChildReference) As Boolean
    'Returns true if successful
    Try
        Dim service As DriveService = ActiveUser.DriveService
        Dim file As Drive.v2.Data.File = service.Files.Get(child.Id).Fetch()
        Dim node() As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Find(nodeKey, True)
        Dim strTitle As String
        If file.FileExtension Is Nothing Then
            strTitle = file.Title
        Else
            strTitle = If(file.Title.EndsWith(file.FileExtension), file.Title, file.Title + file.FileExtension)
        End If
        node(0).Nodes.Add(file.Id, strTitle)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

And here is my FileManager class function:

```
Public Shared Function GetFoldersInFolder(service As DriveService, ByVal folderId As String) As ChildList
    Dim request As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.ChildrenResource.ListRequest = service.Children.List(folderId)
    request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
    Return request.Fetch()
End Function
```

Sorry I had to include so much code, but I tried to include only that which is necessary. I also already have code which allows me to cache the directory structure, but decided it will be hard to implement, since I will have to be checking to make sure things haven't changed... I really just need a faster way of retrieving the directory structure. I know another way of doing this is to have the treeview only populate the subfolders once a user clicks on the parent folder, but I would like to avoid the short pause which comes from waiting for the server to respond to each request, every time the user clicks on a new folder.

I also have a function which retrieves ALL folders:

```
Public Shared Function GetAllFolders(service As DriveService) As FileList
    Dim request As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.ListRequest = service.Files.List
    Dim request2 As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.ListRequest = service.Files.List
    request.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
    Return request.Fetch()
End Function
```

But I can't come up with any efficient way to parse that list to come up with a directory structure... Any ideas? I really appreciate the help. I've been working on this for days...

Answer (score 0):

Your method is reasonable. Sorry it is taking a long time with large Google Drives. I certainly think that you are on the right idea in only populating the child nodes when the user attempts to expand the parent. The pause there is expected, but you can mitigate it somewhat by displaying some feedback to the user, e.g. `Loading...`.

In this age of cloud computing, users expect some delay when loading data from a remote service. This will improve in the future as network speeds improve.